# Docker not mounting volumes other than "C: drive"

Tags: wordpress, docker, virtualbox, mount

I am trying to mount/share the "wordpress image files between the Virtual Box docker instance and my host machine (Windows 10), on to an external USB drive (D:/Projects/), but it does not appear to be working.

I have tried:

- Updating VirtualBox to the latest version,
- Adding the VirtualBox Extension Pack to enable USB 3.0,
- Adding "D:/Projects/" directory as a "Machine Folder" in "Shared Folders",

But on "docker-compose up -d" everything works (wordpress is up and running), but no volumes are visible in the local directory on my host machine, inside "D:/Projects/" directory.

---

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
      
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite

networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation of docker on Windows, check https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/334